# Need a Google Spreed Sheet Formula

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

How do I copy data from one cell of a column to next cell of next column if the data is greater than 2 by using formula?

Now my file is like this:

[image: Initial Sheet]

I want to transfer the data from column B to column C, whose value > than 2.

So, the sheet will be like this:

[image: Resulted Sheet]

Please help me to solve this... Thank You.

Comment: would it not be both simpler to just flag the cells red if over a certain value?

Comment: Formulas can't "move" data, they can only return a value to the cell that they belong to. You need a script to automate something like this.

Comment: As takarii said. If you want to identify outliers, you could just use conditional formatting to highlight them, or copy them over and highlight them.

Answer (score 0):

try this formula:

`=ArrayFormula(
{sheet1!A2:A,
if(sheet1!B2:B<=2,sheet1!B2:B,""),
if(sheet1!B2:B>2,sheet1!B2:B,"")})`

use it in separate sheet to convert existing table(1) to result table(2) from yuor example.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Consider to add a description about what are you proposing.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the values over if they are greater than or equal to five, but moving them is not something you can do with a custom function, you would need apps script running to do that for you.

Here is what you can do: `=IF(B2 > 2, B2, "")` , this will copy the value over if its `>` 2. Just drag this formula down the sheet.

I have also added basic conditional formatting to highlight it as red.

[image]

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jPESVPM8WO2IY--KQJD_2PURsO6bZ8vnr5qbyKdPvx8/edit?usp=sharing)